# How to retrieve the passwords of all accounts in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to retrieve passwords of all accounts (Facebook, Dropbox, Gmail, etc) associated in my Android phone... I have tried the coding below, but not able to get the passwords...

```
    AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account [] acc = am.getAccounts();
    if (acc.length > 0){
        for (int i=0; i<acc.length; i++){
            String password = am.getPassword(acc[i]);
            listedAcc += acc[i] + " Password:" + password.toString() + "\n\n";
        }
        accounts.setText(listedAcc.toString());
```

Can someone troubleshoot this for me... Thanks

Comment: looks like you want to grab all the passwords who installs your app...

Comment: not possible because it is against privacy

Comment: it is just one of my school projects, and i wanna perform something like backup in the android phone, hope i can back up all the accounts passwords... just for a school project...

Comment: I hope there is no way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

From the method API: [Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getPassword%28android.accounts.Account%29)

This method requires the caller to hold the permission AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS and to have the same UID as the account's authenticator.

Comment: i have added this permission in my manifest, but what does "to have the same UID as the account's authenticator" mean?

Comment: I think it means it needs the same android:sharedUserId in AndroidManifest.xml. You can get the same UID only if you sign the APK with the same key.